# Правильное использование return

Tags: javascript, алгоритм, функции, return

Не понимаю, почему когда я вызываю функцию в данном случае, то получаю `undefined`. Функция получает массив и выводит индекс того элемента, у которого сумма элементов слева от него равна сумме элементов справа. В данном случае должно выводить 3.

```js
function findEvenIndex(arr) {
  let leftPart;
  let rightPart;

  function multi(multiArr) {
    let result = 0;
    multiArr.forEach(function(item) {
      result += item;
    });
    return result;
  }

  arr.forEach(function(item, i) {
    if (i < 1) {
      leftPart = [];
    } else if (i === 1) {
      leftPart = [];
      leftPart.push(arr[0]);
    } else if (i > 1) leftPart = arr.slice(0, i);
    rightPart = arr.slice(i + 1, arr.length);
    if (multi(leftPart) === multi(rightPart)) {
      return i;
    } else return -1;
  });
}

console.log(findEvenIndex([1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 2, 1]));
```

Comment: так а вы ничего не возвращаете с функции `findEvenIndex`, вы возвращаете с колбека для форича...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Чуть-чуть подшаманил :

```js
function findEvenIndex(arr) {
  let leftPart = [],
    rightPart,
    // обьявили переменную, в которую будем записывать результат
    // сразу дадим ей значение -1 (ничего не нашли)
    res = -1

  const multi = arr => arr.reduce((a, v) => a += v, 0)

  arr.forEach((item, i) => {
    if (i === 1)
      leftPart.push(arr[0])
    else if (i > 1)
      leftPart = arr.slice(0, i)

    rightPart = arr.slice(i + 1, arr.length)

    if (multi(leftPart) === multi(rightPart))
      // в нужный момент в переменную результата присваиваем реальный результат
      res = i
  })

  // уже после цикла делаем возврат результата с функции
  return res
}

console.log(findEvenIndex([1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 2, 1]))
```